# WTF flag and WTF score for building a hall of fame questions

Tags: feature-request, tags

Doing First Posts Review is often a tedious task because of the unbelievable garbage in them.

But sometimes there are some rare pearls that are just so... funny/crappy/show total misunderstanding/choose what you want / that they would deserve to be compiled in a yearly best of.

I suggest a WTF flag, and a WTF score that would have no impact on reputation but that will be used to build this compilation.

This post is eligible to be WTF tagged  :-)

Comment: Oh come *on*. You can say pretty much the same about something like at least 50% of the front page questions.

Comment: Maybe it wont impact reputation directly but I think this will have a (huge) impact indirectly because this draws more attention to the post. Basicly the same as the meta-effect.

Comment: Stop reviewing please.

Comment: I just take a screenshot when I see something funny. No need to implement site features and waste staff time on this.

Comment: Maybe pointing and laughing at noobz isn't the best way to reverse the growing perception that Stack Overflow is a toxic, inhumane wasteland?

Answer (score 4):

**No** since such flag would violate the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: Posts could be anonymised to respect this principle.

Comment: I don't that this is possible, since every user would recognize his post and also as long as the post isn't deleted every user can find it.

Comment: @sandwood you're free to compile them and post it on somewhere else. We just don't need them here. Oh, and did you mean Hall of *Shame*?

Comment: @AndrewT. "Wall of shame" I think. The term "hall" should reserved just for "hall of fame", where great community contributors united together.